# Sign in to access this site popup. How to get rid of it?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, windows-authentication

I'm getting the sign in popup when landing on my site after changing the Authentication to Windows.

In IIS I disabled Anonymous Authentication and enabled Windows Authentication.  I set Authentication rules to allow an AD user group that the applications user are members of. I get a windows popup box asking for credentials.  I moved NLTM provider to the top and the extended protection is set to accept.  I still get the popup.
We have tried using group policy to push out the credentials.  I'm not sure how that would work anyway since the users are in an AD group and not individually listed.

Does anyone know of a setting in IIS where I can use the Windows Authentication with the AD Group and not Anonymous, yet still avoid the credentials popup?

Update:  Forget NLTM provider.  Read that in an old post. N/A to the problem.

I managed to get the trusted site setting updated with the alias url.  I can land on the site without the popup.  But the app pool does not work to login to database.

Comment: You shouldn't get the popup, it's not really supposed to work like that. From the details provided it's not really clear why it would happen. I would guess maybe somehow the browser isn't talking to the domain controller properly, or the server isn't. Kerberos should normally be the default provider if possible though rather than NTLM. I would guess the solution to your issue is somewhere [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=iis+windows+authentication+prompting+for+credentials), you might have to do some digging.

Comment: You can find tons of such posts over the internet regarding Chrome prompts when Windows authentication is enabled. Merely a browser side issue, so you need to learn Chrome settings and see how to force it to send user credentials in the initial requests. Removed all irrelevant tags.

Comment: Edge is a relevant tag.  That is the default browser we use.  We also have chrome installed.  Didn't work on either one.  Not sure why you removed Edge tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I know about Windows Integrated Authentication for IIS:

Windows authentication can be used when an IIS server is running on a corporate network that uses a Microsoft Active Directory service domain identity or other Windows account to identify users. Therefore, you can use Windows Authentication to determine whether the server is a member of an Active Directory domain.

Windows Authentication supports two authentication protocols defined in the element, Kerberos and NTLM. When you install and enable Windows Authentication on IIS, the default protocol is Kerberos.

If the client browser accesses IIS through the IP address, the access will be treated as a non-local intranet access, only NTLM authentication will be used, and the username and password of the currently logged-in user will not be automatically transmitted to the server, but a dialog box will pop up requiring manual operation. Enter username and password. Unless, these IP addresses are set as local intranet addresses in the browser's local intranet settings.

If the client accesses IIS through the server name, the client logs in as a domain user, and the server is also in the domain, Kerberos authentication will be used to determine whether the user has the right to access IIS resources through the user's authentication ticket. If the client is not logged in as a domain user, or the server is not in the domain, first the current user's username and password will be automatically transmitted to the server for verification. If successful, IIS will allow access to the resource, otherwise access will be denied and the browser will pop up a dialog. The box requires the user to enter a username and password. After entering, the browser will send it to the server again for verification.

Comment: All users are logged in as domain users.  The problem is setting the browser local intranet settings.  I don't control that, and I work with a server admin.  They have set up an alias for the server's name so the url will be simplified.  The admin added to the group policy pushed out to all browser to allow servername.domain.local.  He also added an entry for aliasname.domain.local.  This does not allow user to hit the page without entering credentials.  Does the entry need to contain the domain.local?  Can I just put in aliasname?  I'm not sure how to add this to the browser settings.